# Adding single parameter from URL string to Javascript window.location redirect

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation

What's working: 
The directory page I've created queries a MySQL database and returns the default category of results sorted in order of their proximity to the latitude and longitude coordinates of our city (it loads index.php?cat=1&lat=41.308273&long=-72.927879, for example, to start). When you click a category link (index.php?cat=2), it loads a different category of results following the same sort criteria (passed through the URL string). Then I have the following javascript below (called onclick of a "use my location" button element) that gets and sends the user's geolocation to the query so that the results returned are sorted in order of their proximity to the user's location (e.g., if they are on the edge of the city, the sort will be different than the default sort), except that...

What's not working: 
When I'm on the *second* page (index.php?cat=2..., which shows the default city-based sort for that category's results) and I click the "use my location" button, it correctly gets and sends the user's lat/long but redirects to the first category page (index.php?cat=1...). If I click to the second, the correctly sorted results are there.

Is there a way to append the value of $_GET['cat'] to the end of the window.location string while the function is called? So that that line would read:

window.location='index.php?lat='+position.coords.latitude+'&long='+position.coords.longitude+'&cat='+ValueFromCatVariable;

I'm realize that as a newbie, I'm working a bit beyond my capabilities, but having spent hours trying this and that, I thought I'd try here since I'm just not clear whether it's even possible, and maybe someone would have a quick answer to send me on the right path (I've read that AJAX and JSON may have some solutions, but so far, I'm only used to doing simple page-based passing of variables). Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Tried integrating some URL query parsing code, but unable to see how to make it work as part of the redirect. Wondering if I should move to a form input approach?

```
var y = document.getElementById("getgeo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(redirectToPosition); //getCurrentPosition
    } else { 
        y.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function redirectToPosition(position) {
    window.location='index.php?lat='+position.coords.latitude+'&long='+position.coords.longitude;
}
```

The hope is to get the cat=2 page to be re-sorted with the geolocation-based latitude/longitude without the page being redirected back to the default category (cat=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume other things except getting $_GET['cat'] in js window.location is working fine.

```
<script>
    var cat = "<?php echo $_GET['cat'] ?>"
    console.log("cat = " + cat)
</script>
```

With this you can get cat in js variable and use it.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It works! I tried something like this earlier, but I wasn't sure how to connect the two in order to refer to it in the window.location string, plus I had some typos in the window.location line, which I just corrected above. I think I understand it now, because I was able to added a second button that uses that model but sets the variable to the default lat/long so that I can toggle back and forth, staying on the same category page. Much obliged.